# @angular/cli build issue with default class

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

I am playing around with the @angular/cli tool for projects and building and am having an issue with one of the classes.

I am trying to add a component that is lazyloaded on access of the route:

App route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module'
    }
];
```

And a module that loads the components and routes (currently just a simple component that says "Dashboard"):

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import {
    DashboardComponent,
    DashboardRoutingModule
} from './index';

@NgModule({
    imports: [DashboardRoutingModule],
    declarations: [DashboardComponent]
})

export default class DashboardModule  { }
```

When I run `ng serve` the web page starts as expected and I can develop / see what I am working on.

When I run `ng build` the project builds ok without any issues.

When I run `ng build --prod --aot` it returns an errors and a warnings:

> WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ngfactory.ts
>   31:38-61 "export 'DashboardModule' (imported as 'import1') was not
>   found in '../../../app/dashboard/dashboard.module'
>   WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ngfactory.ts
>   46:23-46 "export 'DashboardModule' (imported as 'import1') was not
>   found in '../../../app/dashboard/dashboard.module'
>   WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ngfactory.ts
>   58:91-114 "export 'DashboardModule' (imported as 'import1') was not
>   found in '../../../app/dashboard/dashboard.module'
>   ERROR in C:/wamp/www/api/data-portal/src/$$_gendir/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ngfactory.ts
>   (1,1): Namespace '"C:/wamp/www/api/data-portal/src/app/dashboard/
>   dashboard.module"' has no exported member
>   'DashboardModule'.C:/wamp/www/api/data-portal/src/$$_gendir/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ngfactory.ts
>   (1,1): Namespace
>   '"C:/wamp/www/api/data-portal/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module"' has
>   no exported member 'DashboardModule'.
>   C:/wamp/www/api/data-portal/src/$$_gendir/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ngfactory.ts
>   (1,1): Namespace
>   '"C:/wamp/www/api/data-portal/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module"' has
>   no exported member 'DashboardModule'.

If I remove the keyword `default` from the export of the Dashboard Module, it builds without any issues however then the app doesn't work as it can't find a `default`, however if I add in the default again it breaks the production build.

Any ideas/thoughts as to what I am doing wrong? I am really confused as `ng serve` works and `ng build` works with the `default` keyword, but `ng build --prod --aot` does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by changing the way I was doing the routing.

Instead of:

```
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module'
}
```

I used:

```
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
}
```

Removing the need for a default in the dashboard module - works perfectly in case anyone has the same issue as me.